# How to launch more than one instance using knife ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, knife

How launch more than one instance using knife ec2, also is there any need of delay between launching the instances.

While lauching multiple instance using `knife ec2` can we attach different roles to different instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, when it comes to `knife ec2` or any of the cloud providers, I use a wrapper bash+tmux script around it.

```
#!/bin/bash

tmux new-session -s build -n build -d "echo 'start'"
tmux new-window -t build -n backend
    tmux send-keys -t build:backend  "knife ec2 server create --server-name backend -N backend -E playpen -f 5 -I 9aa3b52b-1471-413f-8b2b-0fbc756491b4 -r 'role[base], recipe[ops::mysql_db_setup], ' -d ubuntu10.04-v4 --private-network" Enter
tmux new-window -t build -n web01
tmux send-keys -t build:web01 "knife ec2 server create --server-name web01 -N web01 -E playpen -f 5 -I 9aa3b52b-1471-413f-8b2b-0fbc756491b4 -r 'role[base],role[web]' -d ubuntu10.04-v4 --private-network" Enter
tmux new-window -t build -n web02
tmux send-keys -t build:web02 "knife ec2 server create --server-name web02 -N web02 -E playpen -f 5 -I 9aa3b52b-1471-413f-8b2b-0fbc756491b4 -r 'role[base],role[web]' -d ubuntu10.04-v4 --private-network" Enter
tmux new-window -t build -n background01
tmux send-keys -t build:background01 "knife ec2 server create --server-name background01 -N background01 -E playpen -f 2 -I 9aa3b52b-1471-413f-8b2b-0fbc756491b4 -r 'role[base],role[background]' -d ubuntu10.04-v4 --private-network" Enter

tmux attach-session -t build
tmux select-window -t build
```

Or at least something to that effect.